# Finding Cyclops Numbers in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a problem in which I need to return True or False after checking to see whether a number is a cyclops number or not. A cyclops number is made up of odd number of digits, consists of only one zero and that zero is located in the middle. Here's what I have so far:

```
def is_cyclops(n):
  strNum = str(n)
  for i, el in enumerate(strNum):
    if(len(strNum) % 2 == 0):
      return False
    else: 
      # find middle number is zero 
      # no other zeros exist 
      # return True 
is_cyclops(0) # True
is_cyclops(101) # True
is_cyclops(1056) # False
is_cyclops(675409820) # False
```

How can I find the median number (without using numpy) & ensure it is a zero, and it is the only zero that exists in that number?

Comment: Do you mean median or do you mean the digit in the middle of the number?

Comment: Hi @jakub, I believe, the middle number. I used the word median but upon reflection, I don't think that's entirely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```py
def is_cyclops(num: int) -> bool:
    str_ = str(num)
    if not len(str_) % 2:
        return False
    if not str_.count('0') == 1:
        return False
    mid_index = len(str_) // 2
    if str_[mid_index] == '0':
        return True
    return False

print(
    is_cyclops(0),
    is_cyclops(101),
    is_cyclops(1056),
    is_cyclops(675409820)
)
```

Output:

```py
True True False False
```

Comment: this is incredible!! I'm learning so much more python with your solution. I've never seen "-> bool" before. Thank you so much.

Comment: Lol I know I'm replying nearly two years later, but thanks, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

As it looks like you've had a good attempt here, I'll help out.

```
def is_cyclops(n):
    strNum = str(n)

    if(len(strNum) % 2 == 0):
      return False
    else:
      middle_index = len(strNum)//2
      if strNum[middle_index] != "0": return False # find middle number is zero 
      if strNum.count("0") > 1: return False # no other zeros exist 
      return True 
is_cyclops(0) # True
is_cyclops(101) # True
is_cyclops(1056) # False
is_cyclops(675409820) # False
```

Comment: @Pyzard: The length is guaranteed to be odd. Dividing by 2, rounding down, is the correct way to get the middle index of an odd length sequence when the sequence uses 0-up indexing (which Python does). e.g. Five element sequence gets index 2 (for indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), which is correct. Even for even length sequences, your correction would go the wrong way, as 4 // 2 + 1 is 3, which is the *last* index in a four element sequence. And adding `0.5` would be all kinds of weird; Python rounds-half-to-even, so 4 / 2 + 0.5 would be 2.5 and round to 2, while 6 / 2 + 0.5 would be 3.5 and round to 4.